# Is there possibly a memory leak in the following node js code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks

I noticed that the following node js code keeps on using more and more memory as it runs. Not sure when/if the GC kicks in, but the heap size grows steadily from 7.7 to about 8.5 MB in as little as 3 minutes. Could someone please tell me if there is a memory leak and why, and whether it would cause a problem if the code ran indefinitely? Thanks!

```
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
var queue = [];
var count = 0;

function queueAdd(){
    setTimeout(function (){
        if(queue.length >= 1){
            eventEmitter.emit('next'); 
            return queueAdd(); 
        };
        count += 1;
        queue.push(count.toString());
        queueAdd();
    },1000);
}

eventEmitter.on('next', function (){
    console.log(queue.shift());
});

queueAdd();
```

Comment: 7.7 to 8.5 doesn't sound that big a step yet - does the growth actually persist if you continue above 3 minutes?

Comment: @doldt I've been monitoring it for >1000 seconds now and the memory usage has grown to 14 MB

Comment: Can you check your stack and see if it is growing. Your use of recursion here is a little unconventional and it might be resulting in an ever growing stack.

Comment: @bhspencer - It doesn't look like there are any "blocking" calls. Do you think the stack could be effected here?

Comment: @bhspencer It'not recursion.

Comment: The line return queueAdd();  troubles me. try putting that on two separate lines. queueAdd();  and then return; I suspect as you have it you are adding a never ending list of queueAdd pointers to the return address stack.

Comment: @bhspencer stack doesn't seem to be growing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no leak in the code you posted. It possible that nodejs is not compacting heap for some reason. You add `--trace-gc` to tell node to log garbage collection events. You can also use `--max-new-space-size=1024` to tighten the amount of memory available to new allocations to force more frequent GCs and help verify whether there's a leak or just infrequent compaction.

Comment: You're right. Heap size does stabilize in the long run